# Unknow error when play audio with media player in android

Tags: android, media-player

In my app, i have to play the songs from external storage. It work fine , but some time media player stop without error log or warning. Here is my logcat appear when this happening:

```
04-12 11:18:31.528: D/jdwp(12465): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x39
04-12 11:18:31.541: D/jdwp(12465): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3B
04-11 22:39:16.320: D/dalvikvm(16048): threadid=10: interp stack at 0x4bf6e000

04-11 22:39:16.326: D/jdwp(16048): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3B

04-11 22:39:16.436: D/dalvikvm(16048): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x4bfa8000

04-11 22:39:16.436: D/dalvikvm(16048): threadid=11: calling run()

04-11 22:39:16.437: D/dalvikvm(16048): threadid=12: interp stack at 0x4bfb0000

04-11 22:39:16.437: D/dalvikvm(16048): threadid=12: calling run()

04-11 22:39:16.476: D/dalvikvm(16048): threadid=13: interp stack at 0x4bfb8000

04-11 22:39:16.476: D/dalvikvm(16048): threadid=13: calling run()

04-11 22:39:16.486: D/dalvikvm(16048): threadid=13: exiting

04-11 23:42:26.737: D/dalvikvm(3500): threadid=13: bye!

04-11 23:42:26.737: D/dalvikvm(3500): threadid=0: freeing

04-11 23:42:26.753: D/ACRA(3500): Using default Report Fields

04-11 23:42:26.765: D/ACRA(3500): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.pakagename/files
```

I'm trying with `media.setdatasource(file.getFD)` as suggest from some topic, but it not work
I need your help , thanks

Here is my code when create mediaplayer:

```
try {
        try {
            Log.d("file music ", musicObject.getFilePath());
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(musicObject.getFilePath());
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());

        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.playlistEntry = musicObject;

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.e("",
                        "onCompletion getPlaylistPlaybackMode "
                                + mPlaylist.getPlaylistPlaybackMode()
                                + " seleected track id "
                                + mPlaylist.getSelectedIndex());
                mMPHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_MP_RELEASE, 500);
            }

        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.preparing = false;

                // we may start playing
                if (mPlaylist.getSelectedTrack() == mediaPlayer.playlistEntry
                        && mediaPlayer.playAfterPrepare) {
                    mediaPlayer.playAfterPrepare = false;
                    play();
                    Log.d("onprepared", "true");
                }

            }

        });

        mediaPlayer
                .setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp,
                            int percent) {
                        if (mPlayerEngineListener != null) {
                            mPlayerEngineListener.onTrackBuffering(percent);
                        }
                    }

                });

        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.w(UILApplication.TAG, "PlayerEngineImpl fail, what ("
                        + what + ") extra (" + extra + ")");
                CommonUtils.writetoFile( "PlayerEngineImpl fail, what ("
                        + what + ") extra (" + extra + ")", context);

                if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) {

                    if (mPlayerEngineListener != null) {
                        mPlayerEngineListener.onTrackStreamError();
                    }
                    stop();
                    return true;
                }

                if (what == -1) {
                    long failTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (failTime - mLastFailTime > FAIL_TIME_FRAME) {

                        mTimesFailed = 1;
                        mLastFailTime = failTime;
                        Log.w(UILApplication.TAG, "PlayerEngineImpl "
                                + mTimesFailed
                                + " fail within FAIL_TIME_FRAME");
                    } else {

                        mTimesFailed++;
                        if (mTimesFailed > ACCEPTABLE_FAIL_NUMBER) {
                            Log.w(UILApplication.TAG,
                                    "PlayerEngineImpl too many fails, aborting playback");
                            if (mPlayerEngineListener != null) {
                                mPlayerEngineListener.onTrackStreamError();
                            }
                            stop();
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.preparing = true;
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (mPlayerEngineListener != null) {
            mPlayerEngineListener.onTrackChanged(mPlaylist
                    .getSelectedTrack());
        }

        return mediaPlayer;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And when play:

```
if (mCurrentMediaPlayer != null
                && mCurrentMediaPlayer.musicObject != mPlaylist
                        .getSelected()) {
            try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.stop();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // this may happen sometimes
        } finally {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
            mCurrentMediaPlayer = null;
        }
            mCurrentMediaPlayer = build(mPlaylist.getSelectedTrack());
        }
```

And Handeler in `oncompletionListener`:

```
protected Handler mMPHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == MSG_MP_RELEASE) {
            if (mPlaylist.getPlaylistPlaybackMode() == PlaylistPlaybackMode.SHUFFLE_AND_REPEAT1
                    || mPlaylist.getPlaylistPlaybackMode() == PlaylistPlaybackMode.REPEAT1) {
                Log.e("",
                        "onCompletion getPlaylistPlaybackMode "
                                + mPlaylist.getPlaylistPlaybackMode()
                                + " seleected track id "
                                + mPlaylist.getSelectedIndex());
                play(mPlaylist.getSelectedIndex());
            } else if (!mPlaylist.isLastTrackOnList()
                    || mPlaylist.getPlaylistPlaybackMode() == PlaylistPlaybackMode.REPEAT
                    || mPlaylist.getPlaylistPlaybackMode() == PlaylistPlaybackMode.SHUFFLE_AND_REPEAT) {
                next();
            } else

            {
                stop();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Edit: Util now , i dont know what happen.It appear when i do some or alot of background action out side app

```
 04-12 11:18:31.528: D/jdwp(12465): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x39
04-12 11:18:31.541: D/jdwp(12465): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3B
```

Maybe it is problem

Edit: i found some information from android deverloper web page:

> The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low
>   and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user
>   focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus,
>   then it's less likely to be killed, and if the service is declared to
>   run in the foreground (discussed later), then it will almost never be
>   killed. Otherwise, if the service was started and is long-running,
>   then the system will lower its position in the list of background
>   tasks over time and the service will become highly susceptible to
>   killing—if your service is started, then you must design it to
>   gracefully handle restarts by the system. If the system kills your
>   service, it restarts it as soon as resources become available again
>   (though this also depends on the value you return from
>   onStartCommand(), as discussed later). For more information about when
>   the system might destroy a service, see the Processes and Threading
>   document.

How i cant fix it?

Comment: Shpw us your code....

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, pls see my code from my edit!!

Comment: You logs dont show much right now, but if you change `e.printStackTrace();` to `Log.e("ErrorTag", e.getMessage(), e);`  and you should start to see the errors in your logs and get more meaningful error reporting

Comment: I've tried it with no luck, i dont thinks the problem with e.printstackstrace() , it look like system stop my service without any log